# Using find file in shell script using wildcards in input and output

Tags: shell, scripting, find

I have a list of files (see below) I need to merge into separate files (`merge1`, `merge2`).  `merge1` would contain `file1a_1` and `file1a_2`;  `merge2` would contain `file2a_1`, `file2a_2`.

I tried

```
find . -name "file*_*"  -exec cat {} \; >> mergefile*
```

i.e. Files:

```
file1a_1
X1a_2
file1a_3
file1b_1
file1b_2
file1b_3
```

The shell script puts all the files into merge file and doesn't separate them out individually.

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Are the `file*_*` files in subdirectories, or all in the current directory? I'm assuming the `X1a_2` is meant as an example of a file to omit?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
find . -name 'file[0-9]*_*' -type f -exec awk '
  FNR == 1 {
    output = FILENAME
    sub(/.*\/file/, "", output)
    sub(/[^0-9].*/, "", output)
    output = "merge" output
  }
  {print > output}' {} +
```

Note that `find` finds files in an unspecified order, so files will be merged in an unspecified order.

Note that if all the files for a given `merge` file are empty, the `merge` file won't be created. If you'd rather get an empty `merge` file in those cases, and if your `awk` is the GNU ones, you can change the above to:

```
find . -name 'file[0-9]*_*' -type f -exec gawk '
  BEGINFILE {
    output = FILENAME
    sub(/.*\/file/, "", output)
    sub(/[^0-9].*/, "", output)
    output = "merge" output
    printf "" > output
  }
  {print > output}' {} +
```

Comment: your code not work on my `debian 9.3`

Comment: and too this code not work!! `find . -name 'file[0-9]*_*' -type f -exec awk '{print FILENAME}'  {} +` why?!

Comment: this command `find . -name 'file[0-9]*_*' -type f ` work and show file name ..

Comment: @بارپابابا, in which way does it _not work_? Do you get an error? What's your shell? If using `fish` or `rc`, you'd need to quote `{}`.

Comment: i use `bash` in default! http://bayanbox.ir/view/4393624869319520231/Screenshot-2018-03-30-10-26-09.png

Comment: @بارپابابا, your files are empty, there's nothing to merge `FNR == 1` never matches because none of your files have any record.

Comment: @بارپابابا, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

*If* the files are all in the current directory, you could hard-code a loop through the highest number that you might merge (100 in the example below):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for((index=1;index<100;index++))
do
  inputs=( "file${index}"*_* )
  if [ "${#inputs[@]}" -gt 0 ]
  then
    cat -- "${inputs[@]}" > "merge${index}"
  fi
done
```